# Populate Userform Labels

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I have a situation where I need to populate the labels on a userform based on the selected language.

Sheet 2 contains a list of the label names in column C, starting at row 9, and the adjacent columns D to F contain the caption text each label should have base on the selected language. Selecting a language populates cell C2 with a number which represents the column to use, ie columns 4, 5 or 6 (languageCol). I have tried various iterations of the following code but I am unable to populate the labels.

```
Dim Cell As Range
Dim l As Integer
Dim languageCol As Integer

languageCol = Sheet2.Range("C2")

For Each Cell In Sheet2.Range("C9", Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Cells
    For l = 1 To 5
        Me.Controls("frm_Details" & l).Caption = Cell.Offset(, languageCol).Text
    Next l
Next Cell
```

Comment: Are you getting an error, or does the problem manifest in another way?

Comment: No errors reported but the labels are not populating

Comment: Inside your `l` loop there, add a line: `Debug.Print Cell.Offset(, languageCol).Address` to check where it's looking for the text.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The issue was how I was defining the name for each control on the form. Solution below

```
For Each Cell In Sheet2.Range("C9", Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Cells
    Me.Controls(Cell.Text).Caption = Cell.Offset(, languageCol).Text
Next Cell
```